# How to parse a json in python which was created with json stringfy using javascript

Tags: javascript, python, json

I have an object i stringyfied in JavaScript and i want to parse it in python. However i get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "main.py", line 7, in
>
> y = json.loads(x)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/**init**.py", line 357, in loads
> return _default_decoder.decode(s)   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
> obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())   File "/usr/lib/python3.8/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode
> obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx) json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 18 (char 17)

**javascript**

```
const text = 'K said "Hello World" ';

const obj = {
  text: text
}

const stringified = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

output of stringified is : `{"text":"K said \"Hello World\" "}`

**python**

```
import json

x = '{"text":"K said \"Hello World\" "}'

y = json.loads(x)

print(y)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a **raw** string in order to **jsonify** this as the string is not properly parsed in python. Putting a **r** before the string should do the work

```py
import json

x = r'{"text":"K said \"Hello World\" "}'

y = json.loads(x)

print(y)
>>> {'text': 'K said "Hello World" '}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

The variable `x` has to be

```
x = "{\"text\":\"K said \"Hello World\" \"}"
y = json.loads(x)

print(y)
>>> {'text': 'K said "Hello World" '}
```